Docker Not Allowing me to use --from tag
I'm trying to build an image but I keep getting the following error:
failed to solve: dockerfile parse error on line 16: unknown flag: from:builder
Here's my docker file:
FROM maven:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

RUN mvn package clean

FROM openjdk:21-jdk-slim

VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE=target/spring-mysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

COPY --from:builder /app/${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]


Your syntax is wrong. It should be like this:
COPY --from=builder /app/${JAR_FILE} app.jar

When in doubt, turn to Dockerfile reference.
You use = to separate the argument key (from) from the value (builder). : is only used in the context of --from when separating an image from it's tag, like --from=nginx:latest.
